# Receiving AttributeError because 'str' has no write function?

Tags: python-3.x

My function's goal is to write user input data back to a JSON file that my program is using to define words. The error comes in at the json.dump, as its telling me that "data.json" is a string and not a file. Any ideas why?

```
def add_word(nw):
    yn = input("Do you want to add this word? \nType 'N' for No and 'Y' for Yes\n")

    yn = yn.upper()
    if yn == "Y":
        add_def = input(f"Please define {nw}")
        add_data = {nw:add_def}
        add_data.update({nw:add_def})
        json.dump(add_data,"data.json")
        return f"Data updated"
    else:
        return "Nothing added."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dump` expects a "file like object", not a file **name**. The easiest approach would be to `open` the file:

```py
with open('data.json', 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(add_data, f)
```